# Extract metadata from xm s3m mod it tracker music file etc. to command line

Tags: music, file-metadata

I'm trying to extract the metadata from tracker music files. The only tool that was able to provide at least something

```
$ file aa_arofl.xm 
aa_arofl.xm: Fasttracker II module sound data Title: "Archons of light    \032FastTracker v2.00   \004\001\024\001"
```

VLC [allows](https://superuser.com/questions/348159/) me to see the metadata in the GUI but I can't find information on how to get it into the command line output. Any ideas?

Comment: [This](ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/disk1/sourceforge/u/uf/ufmod/XM%20file%20format%20specification/FastTracker%20II,%20ADPCM%20XM%20and%20Stripped%20XM/XM_file_format.pdf.gz) compressed PDF is the most detailed source I have found on this format, and it doesn't tell how to extract the metadata. You can search through the VLC source, I have not gone that far. VLC might use some non-open source library to extract this data.

Comment: How did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC VLC uses the [TagLib Audio Meta-Data Library](http://taglib.github.io/) to provide the metadata from `Fasttracker II Extended Modules`.

Provided with the source code, there are examples on how to use the lib. You may want to take a look at `examples/tagreader.cpp`, which does what you want:

```
$ ./a.out ../../test/aa_arofl.xm 
******************** "../../test/aa_arofl.xm" ********************
-- TAG (basic) --
title   - "Archons of light    "
artist  - ""
album   - ""
year    - "0"
comment - "Greetings thou music-
lover !

Lo and behold!
A new production from
(c) ArchAngel is now
removing some of thy
blessed harddiskspace
in hope of bringing
some joy into this
cruel world...

My humble greetings
this time, goes to:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg can do it.

`ffprobe dualtrax-the_travel_to_orion.xm`

gives:

```
...
Input #0, libmodplug, from 'dualtrax-the_travel_to_orion.xm':
  Metadata:
    name            : the travel to orion!
    instrument      : dualtrax/cro/orion/nmg
                    : and again a nice chipt
                    : une for orion-keygens!
                    : hope you like it :]
                    : dedicated to neoman
                    : march2001
    sample          : the travel to orion!
                    : Drum
    extra info      : 11 patterns, 8 channels, 6/32 instruments, 2/9 samples
...
```

You can export metadata into a file in field=value format:

`ffmpeg -i dualtrax-the_travel_to_orion.xm -f ffmetadata metadata.txt && cat metadata.txt`

gives:

```
;FFMETADATA1
name=the travel to orion!
instrument=dualtrax/cro/orion/nmg\
and again a nice chipt\
une for orion-keygens!\
hope you like it :]\
dedicated to neoman\
march2001
sample=the travel to orion!\
Drum
extra info=11 patterns, 8 channels, 6/32 instruments, 2/9 samples
encoder=Lavf57.71.100
```